# Python: What is Wrong With This datetime.strptime Parsing?

Tags: python

I try to parse a string into a `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime
last_time = '2018-06-01T19:00:00.000000000Z'
datetime.strptime(last_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

unfortunately, this fails:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-06-04T08:44:10.000000000Z' \
does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

What am I doing wrong?

This describes the parameters for parsing:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter `%f` need `microseconds` precision, check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> When used with the strptime() method, the `%f` directive accepts from **one to six digits** and zero pads on the right. `%f` is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available).

So add last zeros with `Z`:

```
from datetime import datetime
last_time = '2018-06-01T19:00:00.000000000Z'
a = datetime.strptime(last_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000Z')
```

Or remove last 4 values:

```
from datetime import datetime
last_time = '2018-06-01T19:00:00.000000000Z'
a = datetime.strptime(last_time[:-4], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print (a)
2018-06-01 19:00:00
```

Comment: What's the issue with original?  Why the extra `000`?

Comment: He specifies the `Z` being in the wrong place based on the previous `%f`, since `%f` refers to microseconds